# Checking if a multiple of a number / date is within a range of numbers / dates

Tags: python, range, python-datetime, algebra

I am working on recurring events in a calendar.
I have a base recurring event with start datetime = **S** and a recurring start datetime of **S + N×Δt**, where N is the *Nth* occurrence and Δt is the separation between each occurrence.

What is the most efficient way of finding all occurrences of this event over a specific datetime interval?

Example:
Event has an initial datetime (2021, 10, 29, 10, 0) and occurs at an interval of 10 days.
I want to solve for N when N is between 2022-05-06 00: and 2022-06-05, so datetime(2022, 05, 06, 0, 0) <= N < datetime(2022, 06, 05, 0, 0)

Can this be done in a more elegant way than iterating over each minute within that range and performing a Euclidian division?

I am using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for anyone looking. This will give you the values of N over which you have to iterate to find the occurrences within the given range.

```
occurrence_start = int(input('Occurrence start: '))
occurrence_end = int(input('Occurrence end: '))
delta = occurrence_end - occurrence_start
i = int(input('Separation: '))
start = int(input('Interval start: '))
end = int(input('Interval end: '))
print('Range is between N={} and N={}'.format((start - occurrence_start + delta)//i, (end - occurrence_end - delta)//i))
```